# UIView animateKeyFramesWithDuration not starting at correct times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cakeyframeanimation

I'm confused as to why this isn't working. I these three events to occur one after the other. First one zooms and Image out, second one fades in a background and third one animates the first image. But it actually occurs the other way round? Have I done something silly ?

```
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [v setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 125, self.view.center.y - 125, 250, 250)];
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.50 relativeDuration:0.75 animations:^{
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.fullView
                              duration:0
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:NULL
                            completion:NULL];

            [self.fullView setHidden:NO];
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:1.50 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            v.animationImages = [self.imageDict objectForKey:id];
            v.animationRepeatCount = 1;
            [v startAnimating];
        }];
    }
    completion:nil];
```

EDIT//
Aside from the typo (1.50 for `addKeyFrameWithRelativeStartTime`), the third block wasn't working because the `UIImageView startAnimating` method needs to be placed in the completion block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks suspicious. The last key frame animation that you have added has a relative start time of 1.5. What does that do ? It should be within the range of 0 to 1.

From apple documentation,

**frameStartTime**

> The time at which to start the specified animations.
>   This value must be in the range 0 to 1, where 0 represents the start
>   of the overall animation and 1 represents the end of the overall
>   animation. For example, for an animation that is two seconds in
>   duration, specifying a start time of 0.5 causes the animations to
>   begin executing one second after the start of the overall animation.

**frameDuration**

> The length of time over which to animate to the
>   specified value. This value must be in the range 0 to 1 and indicates
>   the amount of time relative to the overall animation length. If you
>   specify a value of 0, any properties you set in the animations block
>   update immediately at the specified start time. If you specify a
>   nonzero value, the properties animate over that amount of time. For
>   example, for an animation that is two seconds in duration, specifying
>   a duration of 0.5 results in an animation duration of one second.

I am quite sure that fixing the value to be within the range will do some good change. But, I am not sure if it fixes your issue as I dont understand your animation code.

Comment: Oops the 1.5 was a typo - i've changed it to 0.5 now. The snippets from the docs are useful - I'll play round with that now.